# Meteor JS, allow update

Tags: meteor

I trying to update mongo record and get the error "Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]"

This is code example

```
'click .toActive': function () {
// ...
    var teamId = Session.get('teamId'); 
    console.log(teamId);
    teams.update({_id: teamId, "players.id": this.id}, {$set: {"players.$.status": "active"}});
}

teams.allow({    
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        //...
        return true;
    }
})
```

What should i do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you need to update by _id only.

```
teams.update({_id: teamId}, { your updates });
```

instead of

```
teams.update({_id: teamId, "players.id": this.id}, {$set: {"players.$.status": "active"}});
```

Manage how you're updating your sub document  differently.

Comment: My apologies, i did not show paths to files in my question. path for 'click .toActive' is ./client/smth.js and path for allow-deny rules is ./collections/teams.js